# How to create connection pool for hive JDBC

Tags: jdbc, hive, connection-pooling, jdbctemplate

I am using the JDBC template to perform bulk insert operation into hive. Inserts are very slow.
I tried to create a connection pool using HikariCp, but I am getting the below error while creating the pool:
   `Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (Method not supported.)`

Datasource properties:

```
spring.datasource.type= com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
spring.datasource.maximum-pool-size = 50
spring.datasource.minimum-idle = 2
spring.datasource.jdbcUrl = jdbc:hive2://url
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
spring.datasource.driverClassName = org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver
```

Dependencies:

```
<depencency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>



<depencency>
    <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
    <artifactId>HikariCp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Please help.

Comment: As far as I know that message is a warning that is logged when the pool is initializing and checks feature support, it doesn't prevent your from using HikariCP. What is your actual problem?

Comment: okay, despite using HikariCp, a single record is getting.inserted.

Comment: So, the problem as described in your question does not exist. If you have a different problem, then describe that problem in your question.

Comment: Why I m seeing that error only with hive datasource, not with postgres?

Comment: If you are talking about the warning: likely because Hive does not implement get/set network timeout, and PostgreSQL does.

Comment: Okay, any idea on the connection pool no working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214839/discussion-between-mayank-bisht-and-mark-rotteveel).

Comment: Nothing in your question demonstrates that the pool is not working. Provide a [mre] and clearly describe the problem.